# Single model - multiple filtered views

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have data model (dataProvider as ArrayCollection) i want to display in few views , each view should show filtered data.

As you probably know, filterFunction  is property of ArrayCollection,so I can't use this solution (unless creating new instance of ArrayCollection for each view on top original and impementing filterFunction).

Are there better approaches ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ListCollectionView](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html) for each view that use your array, and every time you can pass to it the same array but filtered differently as source...

Comment: In addition, ListCollectionView has the filterFunction property if you still want to go the "filter-down-a-subset-of-the-dataProvider-for-the-view" route.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same ArrayCollection as dataProvider across multiple views, and setting the filterFunction in view1 persists into view2?

You could probably put code to change the filterFunction for each view in that view's "show" event.  If you wanted to default each view to be unfiltered, pass in a function that just returns true.